# use if or set value in java and kotlin

Tags: java, android, performance, kotlin

I need to compare these 2 codes for CPU and RAM usage. who is better?

enableValidation is a Boolean variable and need to set false.

I have 2 ways:
1. use if
2. set false direct

which one is better?

```
way 1:   

     if (enableValidation) {
        enableValidation = false;
     } 

way 2:

    enableValidation = false;
```

Comment: "Way 1" is pointless, and the CPU/RAM difference (if any) would be so negligble they can otherwise be considered equal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

java and kotlin will be translated to byte codes so you can view byte code and detect wich one is larger code than other

as i know from c++ , the way 2 is better but here the resource usage is about nothing !
dont realy care about it

Answer (score 4):

As far as CPU/RAM usage, there is almost no difference between these two mentioned code approaches. While approach one is checking for a redundant condition. Both code means at this point `enableValidation` has to be `false`, no matter what is the situation.

So code readability perspective, better to assign it to false directly.

Comment: On a theory note, the first will be "less performant". But from a realistic perspective, if JIT doesn't optimize the first into the second anyhow then it's still negligible (3 "cycles" vs 1?).